# Is statistical model a set or an ordered pair?

Tags: statistics, reference-request, definition

Consider  the following definitions for **statistical model**

[Definition 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model#Formal_definition)

> In mathematical terms, a statistical model is usually thought of as a
>   pair $(S,P)$, where
>   $S$ is the set of possible observations, i.e. the
>   sample space, and $P$ is a
>   set of probability distributions on $S$.

[Definition II](https://www.amazon.in/All-Statistics-Statistical-Inference-Springer/dp/0387402721)

> A statistical model $\mathfrak{F}$ is a set of distributions (or densities or
>   regression functions).

And I noticed that  several textbooks used the word *statistical model*   bypassing the actual definition.

I have the following doubt

1) Is it an ordered pair or a set as per formal definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hardly makes a difference.

Technically the answer is that it is an ordered pair of a set $S$ and a set $P$ of probabilit distributions on $S$. However, when specifying the set $P$, one has to make a choice of a base set $S$ anyway. Hence one implicitely chooses a set.

To give another example, one may (and usually does) define a topological space as an ordered pair consisting of a set $X$ and a topology $\tau \subseteq \wp(X)$. However, one may informally say that "a topological space is a set of subsets such that ...", where in the definition of the topology the base set is included.

Again, it hardly makes a difference. Whats important is that one needs to specify a set $S$ and a set $P$ of probability distributions. How that is done is conventional.